# how to convert non-continuous integers in column to continuous in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    0
0   3
1   7
2   2
3   0
4   5
5   6
```

I want to relabel the numbers in df[0] so that the order is preserved, but they become continuous, like this:

```
    0
0   2
1   5
2   1
3   0
4   3
5   4
```

In other words, the smallest value should be 0, the second smallest 1, the third smallest 2, etc.

Comment: do you want to arrange your df[0] in ascending order

Comment: no, i dont want to sort or order anything. i want to preserve the ordering, just change the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['cat']=df['0'].astype('category').cat.codes
df

    0   cat
0   3   2
1   7   5
2   2   1
3   0   0
4   5   3
5   6   4
```

If not interested in new column

```
df['0']=df['0'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `rank`

```
df['0'].rank()-1
0    2.0
1    5.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Or

```
df['0'].argsort().sort_values().index.tolist()
[2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: you are fast while I edit to add `rank solution :)

Comment: @AndyL. add another solution :-)

Comment: Wow, I like the 2nd one very much. It's new and creative. I already upvoted. If I can upvote it one more, I definitely would :)

Comment: @AndyL. vote for you already ~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your `df[0]` is number, you may try `rank`

```
df['0'].rank() - 1

Out[138]:
0    2.0
1    5.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Otherwise,

Construct a dictionary mapping values to its ordinal order. Next `map` back to `df[0]`

```
d = {v: ix for ix, v in df[0].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True).items()}    
s = df[0].map(d)

Out[126]:
0    2
1    5
2    1
3    0
4    3
5    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
df.sort_values()
```

to get the values in order from least to greatest, set ascending=True